# How to enable tap, two finger tap, and natural scrolling in Guix?

Tags: x11, xorg, touchpad, synaptic, guixsd

After booting Guix for the first time, I noticed that tapping on touchpad doesn't render any action. Apparently, Guix comes with a default configuration for touchpad allowing me to click on touchpad, which is mostly sufficient, but having tap disabled, which may be tiring with extensive touchpad use. This is similar to [the default configuration one could encounter on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad).

For just in case, I used `xinput list` to find out the name of the touchpad, and `xinput list-props` followed by the touchpad name, to check its capabilities.

Then I found the location of `synclient` binary with `find`, and, consulting the `synaptics(4)` `man` page online, invoked `synclient` with `TapButton1=1` to enable one-finger tap, then with `TapButton2=3` to set two-finger tap to right button event (which brings the right-click menu). While on it, I also enabled horizontal two-finger scrolling with `HorizTwoFingerScroll=1`, as well as natural scrolling by setting the `VertScrollDelta` and `HorizScrollDelta` to the same values which I learned from `xinput list-props` but negative (by adding `-` before each value).

Now, one would typically add this settings to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`. But since this is Guix, the file is not in `/etc` but in the GNU store and the touchpad driver is supposed to be configured in `/etc/config.scm`. [The GNU Guix Reference Manual](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/en/guix.html) for version 1.3.0 doesn't mention how to configure synaptics.

What can I do on a Guix system, so that I do not need configuring the touchpad myself after each login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to enable tap, two-finger tap, natural scrolling, and even the modern GNOME three-finger swipe, is to switch to libinput instead of synaptics driver. There is a [sample configuration to blacklist the xf86-input-synaptics module](https://issues.guix.gnu.org/33189#5), but I decided just to [switch to Wayland altogether](https://guix.gnu.org/en/manual/devel/en/html_node/X-Window.html#X-Window):

```scheme
;;…
  (services (modify-services
;;…
            (gdm-service-type config => (gdm-configuration
               (inherit config)
               (wayland? #t)))
            ))
;;…
```

After reboot, the default session should be wayland, you can check that it is not X11 under the small gear ⚙️ in the right bottom corner of the GDM screen. After login, [you can check the current session from terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355476/423679) with `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

Don't forget to switch "Tap to Click" on in the GNOME control center.

---

*Update*: Guix System is now using `libinput` by default. It is worth noting that `libinput` does not interpret a three-finger swipe, pinch-to-zoom and similar "[touchscreen gestures](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.12.0/gestures.html#gestures-touchscreens)" by itself. Instead, it passes them to Wayland or X client. It just happens that with X those are not configured or does not work (at least in Fedora and Guix), so with `libinput` switching to Wayland is necessary to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

I installed `xf86-input-synaptics` in my user profile with `guix install xf86-input-synaptics` to put `synclient` in path for my user. (This operation completed even without any Internet connection!) With that, I use the following script now:

```bash
#! /run/current-system/profile/bin/bash

# Enable one-finger tap and double tap
synclient TapButton1=1

# Enable two-finger tap to open right-click menu
synclient TapButton2=3

# Enable horizontal scroll with two fingers
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1

# Enable natural scrolling
synclient VertScrollDelta=-"$(synclient | grep VertScrollDelta | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -c 2-)"
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-"$(synclient | grep HorizScrollDelta | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -c 2-)"
```

I chose to store it in `~/.local/bin/synaptics-user-settings` and put [the following autostart file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3863/423679) at `~/.config/autostart/load-synaptics-user-settings.desktop`. (`/home/roman` is my home directory.)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/roman/.local/bin/load-synaptics-user-settings
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Anyway, this feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and edit:

```
Section "InputClass"
...
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
```